# Is there a way to search and retrieve the first image from a site using php?

Tags: php

Is there a way to search for an image and retrieve the url for it using php for another site, sort of like using get_meta_tags, or for example something like the facebook micropublisher, when you paste a url inside, it grabs an image associated with the site, is there a way to do this? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load the page in an XML DomDocument you can use Xpath to retrieve all Image tags. This would even allow you to create a Facebook like pager, so you can chose from several images.

[PHP: Dom Document](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the DOM. Please see this link http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

This will return all the tags using that you can work out theway to get the first one.

This method will screen grab the website and give you as a image. you need Gd library turned on for this.
http://www.perkiset.org/best/php-code/screen_grab_of_browser_window_with_php.html

Comment: The screen grab method you mention is windows-only.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a preg_match

```
$source = file_get_contents("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434932/is-there-a-way-to-search-and-retrieve-the-first-image-from-a-site-using-php");
preg_match_all('`<img.*src="(.*(?:.png|.jpg|.jpeg|.gif))"`U', $source, $matches);
```

Comment: how could i actually spit any information out from that, when i try to echo any information from it it just dispays Array

Comment: try echo $matches[0] or var_dump($matches) or printr($matches)